# C++ search and pull loop exits early without an error code

Tags: c++, excel, loops, visual-c++

I wrote a program that searches for certain Excel files, pulls one cell of data, and then populates to a new Excel sheet. It works on my home computer and laptop perfectly. However, when I run it on a work computer, it only goes through the first iteration of the loop and then terminates with a code 0.

Here is the loop it breaks during (the rest of program runs completely):

```
void popNames() {
    cout << endl;
    int x = 0;
    try {
        Excel::_ApplicationPtr pXL; //Null Pointer
        pXL.CreateInstance(L"Excel.Application"); //Initialize Excel
        for (int h = 0; h < batches; h++) {
            cout << folderName[h] << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                pXL->Workbooks->Open(homeDir + _bstr_t(sDay.c_str()) + "\\" + folderName[h] + "\\" + fileName[x]);
                //Return pointer to worksheet and cells
                Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheet = pXL->ActiveSheet;
                Excel::RangePtr pRange = pSheet->Cells;

                names.push_back(_bstr_t(pRange->Item[5][2])); //Populate names to vector
                pXL->PutDisplayAlerts(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, VARIANT_FALSE); //Turn off save alert
                pXL->Workbooks->Close(); //close workbook
                pXL->Quit();
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (_com_error & error) {
        cout << "Looks like there was an error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
}
```

I have tried eliminating the try/catch pieces, but then it just crashes the program when it encounters the error. Any additional info I am happy to provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check the functions for error statuses, unless their API specifically states that they will throw an exception.  Some APIs will return statuses rather than throw an exception.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I used "GetLastError()", but it delivers a 0. The API is WIN32.